# Tkinter GUI for running HPLC pumps, real-time data visualization

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, data-visualization, matplotlib

#### What I made

I used Tkinter to write a GUI to run some HPLC pumps for my work. The application sends some messages to the pumps via serial connections, reads a response, then logs data to a csv file. 
[image: main window of program]

I use Matplotlib to plot the data in real time, and to let the user plot several sets of data at once.

This is mostly a personal project I am doing in my free time at work, but I am trying to make a good-practices learning experience out of it. Nobody else is going to develop this code, but I am trying to write it to a shareable standard, such that I could include this in a portfolio of sorts one day.

I have already linted the code up to PEP8, with maybe an exception or two.

#### How it is used

The typical workflow is to start a test and afk while it logs and visualizes data. Occasionally, I like to plot several sets of data for comparison. The menu bar > make new plot functionality lets me do this. The plotter window takes file paths and titles to use in the plot legend. Because I make the same plot often (or versions of it) it is helpful to be able to store those file paths and titles (rather than the image itself). I accomplish this by pickling a list to a ".plt" file that I can unpickle later to repopulate the plotter window.
[image]

I am the only person using this program, but I am trying to build it in such a way that others could learn my job function and use it too. To this end, I am trying to make it pretty and intuitive.

Since you won't have the equipment connected some buttons won't work, but most of the app should be available for prodding.

#### My main areas of concern

- Readability

  - I did lint the code, but it still hurts my eyes in some spots... - what do?
- Design

  - UI elements and logic elements are kind of mixed - what do?
    it's not a massive app, but most lines of code are setting up GUI elements
  - I would like to separate the UI and logic more, but I'm not sure how, or if doing so would be "astronaut architecture" for a project of this size
- Object-orientedness

  - I am unsure of if I am using self.foo too much or not enough
  - I can't help but feel the way I am inheriting objects and using them is wrong, such as [here](https://github.com/teauxfu/pct-scalewiz/blob/e1755bf497407a478b4dd4a35e071d0241ebc2c6/source/plotter.py#L169)
  - eg. I don't fully grasp the meaning of what this is doing
  - ````
       def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
           tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
           ...```
    ````
- Portability

  - the code currently imports from the Winsounds module which is only available for Windows machines :(
  - the startup time (and file size) for one-file bundles seems to rapidly grow with additional module 
    imports. is using python in this way to make executables just a bad practice?
  - I want someone else to be able to drop this file on their computer and it "just works"

#### The layout of the code

- core.py is the entry point

  - imports then creates an instance of MainWindow
  - has a thread_pool_executor attribute to handle a blocking loop we make in MainWindow
- mainwindow.py is the bulk of the application

  - imports then creates an instance of MenuBar
  - has some tkinter widgets for user input / data visualization
- menubar.py

  - the menubar for the MainWindow
  - lets user set project directory
  - can create a Plotter object (new tkinter toplevel)
- plotter.py

  - imports and makes a bunch of SeriesEntry objects (customer tkinter widget)
  - can pickle/unpickle the contents of the SeriesEntry objects
- seriesentry.py

  - custom tkinter widget for selecting csv files and which column of data to be plotted

#### The code

[Here's my GitHub repo for the code.](https://github.com/teauxfu/pct-scalewiz/)

There's some sample csv data in the demo/sample_data repo folder if you want to try the plotting feature

### Thanks for your time!

Here's mainwindow.py

```py
"""The main window of the application.
  - imports then creates an instance of MenuBar
  - has some tkinter widgets for user input / data visualization
"""


import csv  # logging the data
from datetime import datetime  # logging the data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # plotting the data
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv  # reading data from csv
import os  # handling file paths
import serial  # talking to the pumps
import sys  # handling file paths
import tkinter as tk  # GUI
from tkinter import ttk
import time  # sleeping
from winsound import Beep  # beeping when the test ends

from menubar import MenuBar


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        # define test parameters
        self.port1 = tk.StringVar()  # COM port for pump1
        self.port2 = tk.StringVar()  # COM port for pump2
        self.timelimit = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.failpsi = tk.IntVar()
        self.chem = tk.StringVar()
        self.conc = tk.StringVar()
        self.savepath = tk.StringVar()  # output directory
        self.project = tk.StringVar()  # used for window title
        self.plotpsi = tk.StringVar()  # for which pump's data to plot
        self.plotstyle = tk.StringVar()

        # set initial
        self.paused = True
        self.timelimit.set(90)
        self.failpsi.set(1500)
        self.savepath.set(os.getcwd())
        self.plotpsi.set('PSI 2')
        self.plotstyle.set('seaborn-colorblind')
        self.outfile = f"{self.chem.get()}_{self.conc.get()}.csv"
        self.build_window()

    def build_window(self):
        """Make all the tkinter widgets"""
        self.menu = MenuBar(self)
        # build the main frame
        self.tstfrm = tk.Frame(self.parent)
        self.entfrm = tk.LabelFrame(self.tstfrm, text="Test parameters")
        # this spacing is to avoid using multiple labels
        self.outfrm = tk.LabelFrame(self.tstfrm,
            text="Elapsed,            Pump1,             Pump2")
        self.cmdfrm = tk.LabelFrame(self.tstfrm, text="Test controls")

        # define the self.entfrm entries
        self.p1 = ttk.Entry(
            master=self.entfrm,
            width=14,
            textvariable=self.port1,
            justify=tk.CENTER
            )
        self.p2 = ttk.Entry(
            master=self.entfrm,
            width=14,
            textvariable=self.port2,
            justify=tk.CENTER
            )
        self.tl = ttk.Entry(
            master=self.entfrm,
            width=30,
            justify=tk.CENTER,
            textvariable=self.timelimit
            )
        self.fp = ttk.Entry(
            master=self.entfrm,
            width=30,
            justify=tk.CENTER,
            textvariable=self.failpsi
            )
        self.ch = ttk.Entry(
            master=self.entfrm,
            width=30,
            justify=tk.CENTER,
            textvariable=self.chem
            )
        self.co = ttk.Entry(
            master=self.entfrm,
            width=30,
            justify=tk.CENTER,
            textvariable=self.conc
            )
        self.strtbtn = ttk.Button(
            master=self.entfrm,
            text="Start",
            command=self.init_test
            )

        # grid entry labels into self.entfrm
        self.comlbl = ttk.Label(master=self.entfrm, text="COM ports:")
        self.comlbl.grid(row=0, sticky=tk.E)
        ttk.Label(
            master=self.entfrm,
            text="Time limit (min):"
            ).grid(row=1, sticky=tk.E)
        ttk.Label(
            master=self.entfrm,
            text="Failing pressure (psi):"
            ).grid(row=2, sticky=tk.E)
        ttk.Label(
            master=self.entfrm,
            text="Chemical:"
            ).grid(row=3, sticky=tk.E)
        ttk.Label(
            master=self.entfrm,
            text="Concentration:"
            ).grid(row=4, sticky=tk.E)

        # grid entries into self.entfrm
        self.p1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=(9, 1))
        self.p2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.W, padx=(5, 3))
        self.tl.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=1)
        self.fp.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=1)
        self.ch.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=1)
        self.co.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=1)
        self.strtbtn.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=1)
        cols = self.entfrm.grid_size()
        for col in range(cols[0]):
            self.entfrm.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)

        # build self.outfrm PACK
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.outfrm)
        self.dataout = tk.Text(
            master=self.outfrm,
            width=39,
            height=12,
            yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,
            state='disabled'
            )
        # TODO: try calling tk.Scrollbar(self.outfrm) directly
        scrollbar.config(command=self.dataout.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.dataout.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

        # build self.cmdfrm 4x3 GRID
        self.runbtn = ttk.Button(
            master=self.cmdfrm,
            text="Run",
            command=lambda: self.run_test(),
            width=15
            )
        self.endbtn = ttk.Button(
            master=self.cmdfrm,
            text="End",
            command=lambda: self.end_test(),
            width=15
            )
        self.runbtn.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=2, sticky=tk.W)
        self.endbtn.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=2, sticky=tk.E)
        tk.Label(
            master=self.cmdfrm,
            text="Select data to plot:"
            ).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
        tk.Radiobutton(
            master=self.cmdfrm,
            text="PSI 1",
            variable=self.plotpsi,
            value='PSI 1'
            ).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)
        tk.Radiobutton(
            master=self.cmdfrm,
            text="PSI 2",
            variable=self.plotpsi,
            value='PSI 2'
            ).grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5)

        # disable the controls to prevent starting test w/o parameters
        if self.paused:
            for child in self.cmdfrm.winfo_children():
                child.configure(state="disabled")

        # set up the plot area
        self.pltfrm = tk.LabelFrame(
            master=self.tstfrm,
            text=("Style: " + self.plotstyle.get())
            )

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.5, 4), dpi=100)
        plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.10, bottom=0.12, right=0.97, top=0.95)
        # TODO: explicitly clarify some of these args
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.pltfrm)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self.pltfrm)
        toolbar.update()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.ani = FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval=1000)

        # grid stuff into self.tstfrm
        self.entfrm.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW, pady=2)
        self.pltfrm.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=3, sticky=tk.NSEW, padx=2)
        self.outfrm.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW, pady=2)
        self.cmdfrm.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW, pady=2)

        # widget bindings
        self.co.bind("<Return>", self.init_test)
        self.comlbl.bind("<Button-1>", lambda _: self.findcoms())

        self.tstfrm.grid(padx=3)
        self.findcoms()
        self.ch.focus_set()

    def findcoms(self):
        """Looks for COM ports and disables the controls if two aren't found"""
        self.to_log("Finding COM ports...")
        ports = ["COM" + str(i) for i in range(15)]
        useports = []
        for i in ports:
            try:
                if serial.Serial(i).is_open:
                    self.to_log(f"Found an open port at {i}")
                    useports.append(i)
                    serial.Serial(i).close
            except serial.SerialException:
                pass
        if useports == []:
            self.to_log("No COM ports found...")
            self.to_log("Click 'COM ports:' to try again.")
            useports = ["??", "??"]
        try:
            self.port1.set(useports[0])
            self.port2.set(useports[1])
            if self.port1.get() == "??" or self.port2.get() == "??":
                self.strtbtn['state'] = ['disable']
            else:
                self.strtbtn['state'] = ['enable']

        except IndexError:
            pass
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    def init_test(self):
        """Collects all the user data from the GUI widgets"""
        self.port1.set(self.p1.get())
        self.port2.set(self.p2.get())
        self.timelimit.set(self.tl.get())
        self.failpsi.set(self.fp.get())
        self.chem.set(self.ch.get())
        self.conc.set(self.co.get())

        self.outfile = f"{self.chem.get()}_{self.conc.get()}.csv"
        self.psi1, self.psi2, self.elapsed = 0, 0, 0
        # the timeout values are an alternative to using TextIOWrapper
        self.pump1 = serial.Serial(self.port1.get(), timeout=0.01)
        print(f"Opened a port at {self.port1.get()}")
        self.pump2 = serial.Serial(self.port2.get(), timeout=0.01)
        print(f"Opened a port at {self.port2.get()}")

        # set up output file
        outputpath = os.path.join(self.savepath.get(), self.outfile)
        print(f"Creating output file at {outputpath}")
        with open(os.path.join(self.savepath.get(), self.outfile), "w") as f:
            csv.writer(f, delimiter=',').writerow(
                                                    [
                                                     "Timestamp",
                                                     "Seconds",
                                                     "Minutes",
                                                     "PSI 1",
                                                     "PSI 2"
                                                     ]
                                                  )
        # disable the entries for test parameters
        for child in self.entfrm.winfo_children():
            child.configure(state="disabled")
        # enable the commands for starting/stopping the test
        for child in self.cmdfrm.winfo_children():
            child.configure(state="normal")

    def to_log(self, msg):
        """Logs a message to the Text widget in MainWindow's outfrm"""
        self.dataout['state'] = 'normal'
        self.dataout.insert('end', f"{msg}" + "\n")
        self.dataout['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.dataout.see('end')

    def end_test(self):
        """Stops the pumps and closes their COM ports, then swaps the button
        states for the entfrm and cmdfrm widgets"""
        self.paused = True
        self.pump1.write('st'.encode())
        self.pump1.close()
        self.pump2.write('st'.encode())
        self.pump2.close()
        msg = "The test finished in {0:.2f} minutes".format(self.elapsed/60)
        self.to_log(msg)
        for child in self.entfrm.winfo_children():
            child.configure(state="normal")
        for child in self.cmdfrm.winfo_children():
            child.configure(state="disabled")

    def run_test(self):
        """Submits a test loop to the thread_pool_executor"""
        if self.paused:
            self.pump1.write('ru'.encode())
            self.pump2.write('ru'.encode())
            self.paused = False
            # let the pumps warm up before we start recording data
            time.sleep(3)
            self.parent.thread_pool_executor.submit(self.take_reading)

    def take_reading(self):
        """loop to be handled by the thread_pool_executor"""
        starttime = datetime.now()
        while (
         (self.psi1 < self.failpsi.get() or self.psi2 < self.failpsi.get())
         and self.elapsed < self.timelimit.get()*60
         and not self.paused
         ):
            rn = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S", time.localtime())
            self.pump1.write("cc".encode())
            self.pump2.write("cc".encode())
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.psi1 = int(self.pump1.readline().decode().split(',')[1])
            self.psi2 = int(self.pump2.readline().decode().split(',')[1])
            thisdata = [
                        rn,
                        self.elapsed,  # as seconds
                        '{0:.2f}'.format(self.elapsed/60),  # as minutes
                        self.psi1,
                        self.psi2
                        ]

            outputpath = os.path.join(self.savepath.get(), self.outfile)
            with open((outputpath), "a", newline='') as f:
                csv.writer(f, delimiter=',').writerow(thisdata)
            nums = ((self.elapsed/60), self.psi1, self.psi2)
            logmsg = ("{0:.2f} min, {1} psi, {2} psi".format(nums))
            self.to_log(logmsg)
            time.sleep(0.9)
            self.elapsed = (datetime.now() - starttime).seconds

        if not self.paused:
            self.end_test()
            for i in range(3):
                Beep(750, 500)
                time.sleep(0.5)

    def animate(self, i):
        """The animation function for the current test's data"""
        try:
            data = read_csv(os.path.join(self.savepath.get(), self.outfile))
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            data = DataFrame(data={'Minutes': [0], 'PSI 1': [0], 'PSI 2': [0]})

        # TODO: this plt stuff can probably go elsewhere
        plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)  # refresh the style
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42895216
        with plt.style.context(self.plotstyle.get()):
            self.pltfrm.config(text=("Style: " + self.plotstyle.get()))
            self.ax.clear()
            self.ax.set_xlabel("Time (min)")
            self.ax.set_ylabel("Pressure (psi)")
            self.ax.set_ylim(top=self.failpsi.get())
            self.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(100))
            self.ax.set_xlim(left=0, right=self.timelimit.get())

            y = data[self.plotpsi.get()]
            x = data['Minutes']
            self.ax.plot(x, y, label=(f"{self.chem.get()}_{self.conc.get()}"))

            self.ax.grid(color='grey', alpha=0.3)
            self.ax.set_facecolor('w')
            self.ax.legend(loc=0)
```

Comment: Dude, this is really impressive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Data vis considerations

Currently you seem to have a fixed time-axis range. Consider scaling it as time passes. I have also written an industrial control project with some features similar to this, but my time display was rendered differently and could give you some ideas:

- The newest data actually appear at the right edge of the graph
- The time axis ranges from a negative earliest-seen time to zero, interpretable as "seconds/minutes/etc. ago"
- The time axis dynamically changes its units based on how much time has elapsed

Unfortunately the code wouldn't be of much use to you since it's in Mono/GTK2, but the algorithm could be used.

Also, your data appear to be exponential in nature. If that holds true I would suggest making the vertical axis logarithmic.

p.s. once your graph is properly scaled you will find that the legend position may need to move to either upper-left or lower-right to avoid occluding your curves.

### Mixing logic and presentation

`MainWindow` was doing good, adhering to GUI-only tasks - right up until `findcoms`. This is pretty clearly a business logic concern and should be separated into a different class and/or module.

`init_test` is a big mix of UI and logic, which you should also attempt to decouple.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration! I’ll play around with putting the vertical axis on a log scale and see how it presents. Since this is pressure vs time data though a logarithmic unit might be confusing to interpret. I’ll look into cleaning up findcoms/ init_test. I think a simple import statement should let me separate the second half of mainwindow into just test logic. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Log scales are easy enough to interpret as long as some basic rules are followed - use a radix of 10; show sub-ticks; show a pale sub-grid and a normal-opacity primary grid; etc. This should be easy to do with `matplotlib`.